# Lualatex and a5 paper format

Tags: luatex, geometry, paper-size

I'm having problems generating a pdf file with A5 format. With `pdflatex` this compiles fine, without, it doesn't.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{A Title}
\author{An Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Goals}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{luatex85}` or `\usepackage{graphicx} ` (assuming that you have the newest luatex).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{luatex85}` or `\usepackage{graphicx}` (assuming that you have the newest luatex).